# What is the word for "intially resisting, but eventually accepting that it's not right"

Tags: single-word-requests

I once knew what it was but I've  forgotten it. I need a specific word for resisting at first but eventually admitting that you're wrong

Comment: Do you mean *capitulate*? Your question is not entirely clear.

Comment: no its not. For example. a feedback coming from your colleague then theres a word that u can use

Comment: that at first your denying but eventually admitted in a formal way/word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**concede**

> admit or agree that something is true after first denying or resisting
>   it.

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/concede)]